# Selecting two rows from another table using one row

Tags: mysql, sql

table1

```
[      id      -      title      -      content      -      class      ]
[      1       -        2        -         3         -        1        ]
[      1       -        2        -         3         -        2        ]
```

table2

```
[      id      -       data      -    permission     -      class      ]
[      a       -        b        -         c         -        1        ]
[      a       -        b        -         c         -        2        ]
```

How can i select the column `data` from table2 while selecting all table1

my query is `SELECT title, content FROM table1 WHERE class = 1`

How can i select column `data` and `permission` in this query?

Comment: How does the second table relate to the first table?

Comment: What is relationship between tables? `class` column?

Comment: @OtoShavadze Yes, the class

Comment: @Siyual the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a simple `JOIN`:

```
Select  T1.*, T2.Data, T2.Permission
From    Table1  T1
Join    Table2  T2  On  T1.Class = T2.Class
Where   T1.Class = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the relationship is based on class:

```
select table1.*,table2.data, table2.permission
from table1 
join table2 on table1.class = table2.class 
where table1.class = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.title, t1.content, t2.data from table1 t1 join table2 t2
on t1.class=t2.class
```